# Purpose of the HTML5 main element

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I've been looking into HTML semantics lately and I was wondering what the real purpose of `<main>` is. I've created two scenarios shown below:

**Scenario one**

```
     <main role="main">
        <header role="banner">
           <hgroup>
              <h1>Header 1</h1>
              <h2>Header 2</h2>
           </hgroup>

           <nav>
              <ul>
                 <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
              </ul>
           </nav>
        </header>

        <section role="region">
           <header>
              <h1>Articles</h1>
           </header>

           <article>
              <header>
                 <h1>Article name</h1>
              </header>

              <p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</p>

              <footer>
                 <a href="#" title="Read more">Read this post</a>
              </footer>
           </article>

           <footer>
              <a href="#" title="Read more">Read this articles</a>
           </footer>
        </section>

        <footer role="contentinfo">
           <p>Page last updated <time datetime="2009-11-04">November 4th, 2009</time></p>
           <address>
              <a title="Posts by Just A Name" href="#">Just A Name</a>
           </address>
        </footer>
     </main>
```

**Scenario two**

```
     <header role="banner">
        <hgroup>
           <h1>Header 1</h1>
           <h2>Header 2</h2>
        </hgroup>

        <nav>
           <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
           </ul>
        </nav>
     </header>

     <main role="main">
        <section role="region">
           <header>
              <h1>Articles</h1>
           </header>

           <article>
              <header>
                 <h1>Article name</h1>
              </header>

              <p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</p>

              <footer>
                 <a href="#" title="Read more">Read this post</a>
              </footer>
           </article>

           <footer>
              <a href="#" title="Read more">Read this articles</a>
           </footer>
        </section>
     </main>

     <footer role="contentinfo">
        <p>Page last updated <time datetime="2009-11-04">November 4th, 2009</time></p>
        <address>
           <a title="Posts by Just A Name" href="#">Just A Name</a>
        </address>
     </footer>
```

Which one would be the best solution and why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to **[W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-main-element/#the-main-element)**, `main` should be used only for content that is unique to that document, so in your case the scenario #2 is the most appropriate.

> The `main` element represents the main content section of the `body` of a
>   document or application. The `main` content section consists of content
>   that is directly related to or expands upon the central topic of a
>   document or central functionality of an application.
>
> Note: the `main` element is not sectioning content and has no effect on
>   the document outline
>
> The `main` content section of a document includes content that is unique
>   to that document and excludes content that is repeated across a set of
>   documents such as site navigation links, copyright information, site
>   logos and banners and search forms (unless the document or
>   applications `main` function is that of a search form).
>
> Authors **MUST NOT** include more than **one** `main` element in a document.
>
> Authors **MUST NOT** include the `main` element as a child of an `article`,
>   `aside`, `footer`, `header` or `nav` element.

Answer (score 1):

The `<main>`-element is used to indicate the primary (main) content of a page. If the `role="banner"` has significant meaning to the content, you should opt for *scenario one*, and two otherwise.

[This describes/explains](http://html5doctor.com/the-main-element/) the `<main>`-purpose pretty well.

The first and foremost reason these elements (`<main>`, `<header>`, `<footer>`, `<section>`, `<article>`, `<nav>`, `<aside>`) were introduced is to indicate the significance to the document outline.

If you were to compile a chapter index of sorts, you'd want to look at the heading-elements within `<main>` and leave out the `<nav>` and `<aside>` portions. This is also the reason why html5 allows multiple `<h1>` elements, as their significance is determined based on the element they reside in (in contrast to HTML < 5, where the heading-elements themselves would indicate significance within the document).

Answer (score 1):

Besides what is already answered, an important point taken from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/main) is:

> `<main>` doesn't contribute to the document's outline; that is, unlike
> elements such as `<body>`, headings such as `<h2>`, and such, `<main>`
> doesn't affect the DOM's concept of the structure of the page. It's
> strictly informative.